# How to delete all records from table in sqlite with Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

My app has two buttons, the first button is for deleting record on user input and the second button is for deleting all records. But when I want to delete data it shows the message
"Your application has been forcefully stopped".

Please check my code and give me some suggestion.

```
public void deleteAll()
{
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   // db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null);
    //db.execSQL("delete * from"+ TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table" + TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
}
```

and

```
public void delete(String id)
{
    String[] args={id};
    getWritableDatabase().delete("texts", "_ID=?", args);
}
```

But it shows the following Log cat error.

```
03-07 15:57:07.143: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.example.MySQLiteHelper.delete(MySQLiteHelper.java:163)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.example.Settings$4.onClick(Settings.java:94)
-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
03-07 15:57:07.153: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are missing a space after the "from", that way the table name is concatenated with the "from" and it gives you an error

Comment: Also you can try using try{} catch(Exception e){Console.WriteLine(e);} to avoid crushing the program and analyze the error.

Answer (score 415, accepted):

You missed a space: `db.execSQL("delete * from " + TABLE_NAME);`

Also there is no need to even include `*`, the correct query is:

```
db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
```

Comment: You can also use db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);

Comment: will this delete the table or delete the table contents?

Comment: It is deleting only the contents of the table. If you want to remove the table, you have to use a DROP TABLE statement (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html)

Answer (score 179):

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

or, if you want the function to return the *count of deleted rows*,

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "1", null);
```

From the documentation of SQLiteDatabase [delete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method:

> To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the whereClause.

Comment: How would I delete everything in a table except where a value is equal to something.

Comment: You'd call delete() with non-null arguments. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 55):

To delete all the rows within the table you can use:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

Answer (score 37):

SQLite doesn't support the `TRUNCATE` command. You should use what you've tried in the previous line:

```sql
DELETE FROM `TABLE_NAME`;
```

*P.S. You can optimize your program by using the same instance of the database connection for all of your queries to the given database instead of creating a new one for every query.*

Answer (score 19):

There's no need to use "execute" function.The following code worked for me:::

```
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null);
    db.close();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM tablename"); //delete all rows in a table
db.close();
```

this work for me :)

Answer (score 5):

try this code to delete all data from a table..

```
String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM table_name ";
Cursor cursor = data1.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Comment: FWIW, `rawQuery()` alone doesn't work as it doesn't execute the SQL.

Comment: rawQuerry() worked for me. But there is an error in this code: getReadableDatabase(). You can do only queries on a read only db. The correct way is to use getWritableDatabase() if you want to perform deletion.

Answer (score 5):

use Sqlit delete function with last two null parameters.

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just Write

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("delete from "+TableName);
```

or

```
db.delete(tablename,null,null);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Truncate SQLite table ?**

Accepted answer is incorrect for truncate.
**In SQLite it is achieved with 2 queries;**

```
1. db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
2. db.execSQL("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name = '"+ TABLE_NAME+"'");
```

**remember the single quote in 2nd query**;

***so why this two queries?***

- OP has asked about trucate.
- which means delete all records and sets auto increment value of that table to 0
- that's what we have done, here. (and truncate command is not available in SQLite [till date answer posted])

Answer (score 3):

I use this class to handle database.I hope it will help some one in future.

Happy coding.

```
public class Database {

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /**
     * Database name
     */
    private static final String DB_NAME = "db_name";

    /**
     * Table Names
     */
    public static final String TABLE_CART = "DB_CART";


    /**
     *  Cart Table Columns
     */
    public static final String CART_ID_PK = "_id";// Primary key

    public static final String CART_DISH_NAME = "dish_name";
    public static final String CART_DISH_ID = "menu_item_id";
    public static final String CART_DISH_QTY = "dish_qty";
    public static final String CART_DISH_PRICE = "dish_price";

    /**
     * String to create reservation tabs table
     */
    private final String CREATE_TABLE_CART = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_CART + " ( "
            + CART_ID_PK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + CART_DISH_NAME + " TEXT , "
            + CART_DISH_ID + " TEXT , "
            + CART_DISH_QTY + " TEXT , "
            + CART_DISH_PRICE + " TEXT);";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CART);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_TABLE_CART);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


     /**
      * CART handler
      */
      public static class Cart {


    /**
     * Check if Cart is available or not
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isCartAvailable(Context context) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        boolean exists = false;

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
        }

        return exists;
    }


    /**
     * Insert values in cart table
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     * @param dishPrice
     * @param dishQty
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean insertItem(Context context, String itemId, String dishName, String dishPrice, String dishQty) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_ID, "" + itemId);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME, "" + dishName);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_PRICE, "" + dishPrice);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY, "" + dishQty);

        try {
            db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CART, null, values);
            db.close();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check for specific record by name
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isItemAvailable(Context context, String dishName) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        boolean exists = false;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART + " WHERE "
                + DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME + " = '" + String.valueOf(dishName) + "'";


        try {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
            cursor.close();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            db.close();

        }

        return exists;
    }

    /**
     * Update cart item by item name
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     * @param dishPrice
     * @param dishQty
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean updateItem(Context context, String itemId, String dishName, String dishPrice, String dishQty) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_ID, itemId);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME, dishName);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_PRICE, dishPrice);
        values.put(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY, dishQty);

        try {

            String[] args = new String[]{dishName};
            db.update(DBHelper.TABLE_CART, values, DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME + "=?", args);

            db.close();


            return true;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get cart list
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static ArrayList<CartModel> getCartList(Context context) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        ArrayList<CartModel> cartList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART + ";";

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

                cartList.add(new CartModel(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY)),
                        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_PRICE)))
                ));
            }

            db.close();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
        }
        return cartList;
    }

   /**
     * Get total amount of cart items
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static String getTotalAmount(Context context) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        double totalAmount = 0.0;

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART + ";";

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

                totalAmount = totalAmount + Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_PRICE))) *
                        Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY)));
            }

            db.close();


        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
        }


        if (totalAmount == 0.0)
            return "";
        else
            return "" + totalAmount;
    }


    /**
     * Get item quantity
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     * @return
     */
    public static String getItemQty(Context context, String dishName) {

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART + " WHERE " + DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME + " = '" + dishName + "';";
        String quantity = "0";

        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                quantity = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CART_DISH_QTY));

                return quantity;
            }


        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return quantity;
    }


    /**
     * Delete cart item by name
     *
     * @param context
     * @param dishName
     */
    public static void deleteCartItem(Context context, String dishName) {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            String[] args = new String[]{dishName};
            db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_CART, DBHelper.CART_DISH_NAME + "=?", args);

            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            db.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}//End of cart class

/**
 * Delete database table
 *
 * @param context
 */
public static void deleteCart(Context context) {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    try {

        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_CART);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

**Usage:**

```
  if(Database.Cart.isCartAvailable(context)){

       Database.deleteCart(context);

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//Delete all records of table
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);

//Reset the auto_increment primary key if you needed
db.execSQL("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET SEQ=0 WHERE NAME=" + TABLE_NAME);

//For go back free space by shrinking sqlite file
db.execSQL("VACUUM");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me. The difference is here with execSQL and rawQuery. The rawQuery use most in searching case and execSQL mostly used in apply operations.

```
   // truncate the table
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getDatabaseName1(String sr) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("delete from Hotel");
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use two different methods to delete or any query in sqlite android

first method is

```
public void deleteItem(Student item) {
 SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
 String whereClause = "id=?";
 String whereArgs[] = {item.id.toString()};
 db.delete("Items", whereClause, whereArgs);
}
```

second method

```
public void deleteAll()
{
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
  db.close();
}
```

use any method for your use case

Answer (score 0):

```
    getContentResolver().delete(DB.TableName.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```

Comment: Please do add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

**Can be usefull.**

```
public boolean deleteAllFood() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            int affectedRows = db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_FOOD, null, null);
            return affectedRows > 0;
        }



public class DBProgram {
    private static DBProgram INSTANCE;
    private Context context;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    private DBProgram(Context context) {
        // burda bu methodu kullanan activity ile eileştiriyoruz
        this.dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public static synchronized DBProgram getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new DBProgram(context);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    //**********************************************
    public boolean updateById(ProgramModel program) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUM_NAME_P, program.getProgName());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUM_DAY_P, program.getDay());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_WEIGHT_P, program.getWeight());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SET_P, program.getSet());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_REPETITION_P, program.getRepetition());
        int affectedRows = database.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_PROGRAM, contentValues, "PROG_ID_P = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(program.getId())});
        return affectedRows > 0;
    }
    //**********************************************


    //**********************************************
    // TODO
    public boolean deleteProgramById(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        int affectedRows = database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_PROGRAM, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID_P + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        // return bize etkilenen sıra sayısınıını temsil eder
        return affectedRows > 0;
    }
    //**********************************************


    //***************************************************
    public boolean deleteProgramByName(String progName) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        final String whereClause = DBHelper.COLUM_NAME_P + "=?";
        final String whereArgs[] = {progName};
        int affectedRows = database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_PROGRAM, whereClause, whereArgs);
        return affectedRows > 0;
    }
    //***************************************************


    //************************************** get Meal
    // TODO  WEB Get All  Meals
    public List<ProgramModel> getAllProgram(String name) {
        List<ProgramModel> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
        ProgramModel food;
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        final String kolonlar[] = {DBHelper.COLUMN_ID_P,
                DBHelper.COLUM_NAME_P,
                DBHelper.COLUM_DAY_P,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_WEIGHT_P,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_SET_P,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_REPETITION_P};

        final String whereClause = DBHelper.COLUM_DAY_P + "=?";
        final String whereArgs[] = {name};
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_PROGRAM, kolonlar, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            food = new ProgramModel();
            food.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID_P)));
            food.setProgName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUM_NAME_P)));
            food.setDay(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUM_DAY_P)));
            food.setWeight(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_WEIGHT_P)));
            food.setSet(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_SET_P)));
            food.setRepetition(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_REPETITION_P)));
            foodList.add(food);
        }
        database.close();
        cursor.close();
        return foodList;
    }
    //**************************************


    //**************************************insert FOOD
    //TODO LOCAL insert Foods
    public boolean insertProgram(ProgramModel favorite) {
        boolean result = false;
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUM_NAME_P, favorite.getProgName());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUM_DAY_P, favorite.getDay());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_WEIGHT_P, favorite.getWeight());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SET_P, favorite.getSet());
        contentValues.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_REPETITION_P, favorite.getRepetition());
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long id = database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_PROGRAM, null, contentValues);
        if (id != 1) {
            result = true;
        }
        database.close();

        return result;
    }
    //***************************************************

    // *******************************  SQLITE HELPER CLASS ******************
    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private final Context context;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PROGRAM_INFO";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME_PROGRAM = "PROGRAM";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        // FOOD
        private static final String COLUMN_ID_P = "PROG_ID_P";
        private static final String COLUM_NAME_P = "PROG_NAME_P";
        private static final String COLUM_DAY_P = "PROG_DAY_P";
        private static final String COLUMN_WEIGHT_P = "PROG_WEIGHT_P";
        private static final String COLUMN_SET_P = "PROG_SET_P";
        private static final String COLUMN_REPETITION_P = "PROG_REPETITION_P";

        private final String CREATE_TABLE_PROGRAM = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_PROGRAM +
                " (" + COLUMN_ID_P + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + COLUM_NAME_P + " TEXT, "
                + COLUM_DAY_P + " TEXT, "
                + COLUMN_WEIGHT_P + " INTEGER, "
                + COLUMN_SET_P + " INTEGER, "
                + COLUMN_REPETITION_P + " INTEGER)";

        private static final String DROP_TABLE_PROGRAM = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME_PROGRAM;

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PROGRAM);

            Util.showMessage(context, "Database Created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_PROGRAM);
            Util.showMessage(context, "Database Upgrated");
            onCreate(db);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            super.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

this metod delate all data from database

```
 public void deleteAll()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that works for me in Unity (in conjunction with the database SQLite).

code C#:

```
public void DeleteAllObj() {
    connectionString = "URI=file:"+Application.dataPath+"/TerrainTools/db/object.sqlite";
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)) {
        dbConnection.Open();
        using(IDbCommand dbCmd =dbConnection.CreateCommand()) {
            dbCmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM 'ObjectMap'";
            using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                dbConnection.Close();
                reader.Close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is simple way to delete:**

```
public void deleteItem(Item item) {
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
String whereClause = "id=?";
String whereArgs[] = {item.id.toString()};
db.delete("Items", whereClause, whereArgs);
}
```

Here `whereClause` is optional, passing null will delete all rows in table. delete function will return number of affected row if `whereClause` passed otherwise will return 0.

> Important Note:   If you want to remove all rows and require count of deleted ones also then pass 1 as `whereClause`.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLite_NET_PCL v1.6.292 in VStudio - a lot of the docs and comments out there seem out dated(I think).

To delete all records

```
public Task<int> DeleteAllEntry()
    {
        return DataBasePath.DeleteAllAsync<tableName>();
    }
```