# How to delete all items from table in SQLite, Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-delete

**CREATE TABLE**

```
private void createSerialDateTable() {
    mDatabase.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SerialDate (\n" +
                    "    id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT SerialDate_pk PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n" +
                    "    name varchar(200) NOT NULL,\n" +
                    "    joiningdate datetime NOT NULL\n" +
                    ");"
    );
}
```

**INSERT TABLE**

```
 String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO SerialDate \n" +
                "(name, joiningdate)\n" +
                "VALUES \n" +
                "(?, ? );";
        mDatabase.execSQL(insertSQL, new String[]{name, joiningDate});
```

**Delete all items from List I try it** But it not working.

```
clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //  serialDateList.clear();
            Cursor cursorSerialDate = mDatabase.rawQuery("DELETE  FROM SerialDate", null);
            cursorSerialDate.close();

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

How can I delete all data definitely.
Please. Help me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all record from table in sqlite with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599741/how-to-delete-all-record-from-table-in-sqlite-with-android)

Comment: Also another solution but it may be heavier drop the table and recreate another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code to delete all rows in a table :

```
database.delete(tablename, null,null);
```

Comment: mDatabase.delete(SerialDate, null,null);
SerialDate Expression Expected !! what should I do plz !!

Comment: Replace SerialDate with "SerialDate"

Comment: If this helped you, please mark as answered so other people can find it easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to create one common method in DataBaseHelper class

```
public void deleteTableF(String tablename) {

               String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + tablename;

               SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();

               db.execSQL(selectQuery);
            }
```

And call deleteTableF method where you want to delete a particular table in your code.

```
SQLiteDatabase db =  = new DataBaseHelper(this); // Dbhelper class object
 db.deleteTableF("table_name");
```

Comment: SerialDate Expression Expected !! what should I do plz !! [link]( imgur.com/hf3QrUs)

Comment: pass your table name in double quotes like mDatabase.delete("SerialDate",null,null)

Answer (score 0):

`rawQuery` is used for select statements to fetch rows.  
Use `execSql` instead or the delete method

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one

```
clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME);
        db.close();

        // Other codes here
    }
});
```

Comment: SerialDate Expression Expected !! what should I do plz !!  [link]( https://imgur.com/hf3QrUs)